# How to list HttpSession objects and size in a ServletFilter without creating performance issues?

Tags: java, performance, servlets, weblogic, httpsession

I´m trying to solve a performance and stability issue in a JEE application caused by some HttpSessions storing large objects. The app is deployed on  Oracle Weblogic Server 12.1.1. but unfortunately I don´t have access to the app code so I´m thinking about creating a ServletFilter to obtain session objects and its size.

Although it seems a theoretical solution, I´m worried about possible performance issues this approach would create on an application that already has performance problems.

I´ll appreciate your comments and ideas on how to do this.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet API does not allow to enumerate all existing sessions. But you could install a [HttpSessionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to get notified when sessions are created and destroyed and keep track of them in an own collection.

Alternatively you could install a [HttpSessionAttributeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html) to get notified when attributes are added and removed from sessions. Maybe the later is enough to identify your performance bottlenecks.